# Expo Vector Icons not appearing on Android - only iOS production build

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-vector-icons

I have icons from

```
import { Ionicons,FontAwesome5,FontAwesome,AntDesign ,MaterialCommunityIcons} from '@expo/vector-icons';
```

and on expo go on iOS they work fine, additionally in TestFlight they work fine. However, on an iOS development build they do not appear, and they do not appear on Android at all.

Here is the error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: The method or property expo-file-system.downloadAsync is not available on ios, are you sure you've linked all the native dependencies properly?]
```

[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: The method or property expo-file-system.downloadAsync is not available on ios, are you sure you've linked all the native dependencies properly?]

Here is the error trace:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: The method or property expo-file-system.downloadAsync is not available on ios, are you sure you've linked all the native dependencies properly?]
at http://10.154.10.148:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in _createSuperInternal
at node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/errors/CodedError.js:10:8 in constructor
at node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/errors/UnavailabilityError.js:2:42 in <global>
at node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/errors/UnavailabilityError.js:9:42 in constructor
at node_modules/expo-asset/node_modules/expo-file-system/build/FileSystem.js:103:37 in downloadAsync
at node_modules/expo-asset/node_modules/expo-file-system/build/FileSystem.js:101:35 in downloadAsync
at node_modules/expo-asset/build/PlatformUtils.js:78:34 in _downloadAsyncUnmanagedEnv
at node_modules/expo-asset/build/PlatformUtils.js:68:41 in _downloadAsyncUnmanagedEnv
at node_modules/expo-asset/build/PlatformUtils.js:39:37 in downloadAsync
at node_modules/expo-asset/build/PlatformUtils.js:35:35 in downloadAsync
at node_modules/expo-asset/build/Asset.js:222:47 in downloadAsync
at node_modules/expo-asset/build/Asset.js:235:5 in Asset
at node_modules/expo-font/build/FontLoader.js:37:29 in loadSingleFontAsync
at node_modules/expo-font/build/FontLoader.js:32:41 in loadSingleFontAsync
at node_modules/expo-font/build/Font.js:98:37 in <anonymous>
at node_modules/expo-font/build/Font.js:104:5 in loadFontInNamespaceAsync
at node_modules/expo-font/build/Font.js:81:39 in loadFontInNamespaceAsync
at node_modules/expo-font/build/Font.js:76:70 in names.map$argument_0
at node_modules/expo-font/build/Font.js:76:35 in loadAsync
at node_modules/expo-font/build/Font.js:69:31 in loadAsync
at node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/build/createIconSet.js:22:40 in Icon#componentDidMount
- ... 6 more stack frames from framework internals
```

I believe the icons are not getting loaded properly but I'm not sure how to address that? I tried installing downgraded versions of expo-file-system and @expo/vector-icons but nothing has worked so far.